# Django CREATING databases dynamically at runtime( NOT ROUTING the requests to right DB)

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, postgresql, multi-tenant

how does one go about creating a new database for each tenant at run time dynamically.

All the examples are hard coded into settingsfile. But when a new tenant,t1, registers,
I would like to create a new database for t1. and when a t2 connects I would like to be able to create that t2_db at runtime which out running any migrations or server restart.
So let say we have a default db where we do our migrations,(empty) we just copy that for t1 and t2.
Or is there a way to run migrations with out restarting the server.
Or do people just restart the server(crazy right)
If not I am thinking docker.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `call_command` function to execute migrations on a designated database without necessitating a server restart. Moreover, you can invoke this command during the database creation process. However, to dynamically route the database, you must incorporate dynamic addition of database connections. It's important to note that `you'll need to add a database connection every time the server restarts`.

```
from django.core.management import call_command


# After creating db. Update the db connection.
settings.DATABASES[f"db_name"] = {
            "ENGINE": "db_engine",
            "NAME": "db_name",
            "USER": "db_user",
            "PASSWORD": "db_password",
            "HOST": "db_host",
            "PORT": "db_port",
        }
call_command("migrate", database="db_name")
```

This code is for refernce only. create seperate function for adding db_connections dynamically.